# How to use sed to delete a line that has some determined fields?

Tags: linux, bash

I have this .txt file in linux that looks like this:

```
Car;Weight;Year;Origin   
Ford Focus;85.2:75:US
Audi A4;78.2;80;Europe
Ford Focus;77.6;90;US
```

(The actual file is longer but is for you to have an idea of what it looks like)
The thing is that I want to delete the line with the Ford Focus whose weigh is 85.2 and year 75,
I've tried using sed this way:

```
sed -i `/Ford Focus/85.2/75/d` cars.txt
```

But it doesn't work, any idea of how could I do it?

Comment: Is your field separator one `;` or `:`? Currently it looks like you are using both.

Comment: The matching line is `Ford Focus;85.2:75` so the command should be `sed -i '/Ford Focus;85.2:75/d' cars.txt`. Not sure why you used slash in between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `;` and `:` as possible field separators and `awk`:

```
awk -F '[;:]' '$1=="Ford Focus" && $2=="85.2" && $3=="75"{next} {print}' cars.txt
```

Output:

```
Car;Weight;Year;Origin   
Audi A4;78.2;80;Europe
Ford Focus;77.6;90;US
```